# Concordância: "Quais populações sentem que seu país está no caminho errado?"

Tags: ortografia, concordância

Ou seria

> Quais populações sentem que *seus países estão* no caminho errado?

Comment: Cuidado com a ambiguidade: Quais populações sentem que o pais deles está no caminho errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

São frases diferentes.

> *Quais populações sentem que seu país está no caminho errado?* — há apenas um país comum às populações;

> *Quais populações sentem que seus países estão no caminho errado?* — há mais de um país das populações;